# Password-less authentication using corporate Active Directory on external (internet) site

Tags: authentication, active-directory, one-time-password, token

I need to restrict access to an external site so that:

- users who are in the corporate network have full access to the site's functionality,
- those who are not - only limited functionality.

In the corporate network users do authenticate against a windows domain. In the network I can set up a server/service which can do the identity verification. This is secure, I have no doubt, especially when it is inside.

The external site is not a part of the domain.

What I suggest to myself is to setup a service, which will authenticated users against, create a secure token and then re-direct users to the external site. So that users will authenticate there without entering password (maybe not even login).

I'm in doubt: how this can be done? How secure this can be? How much heavy/crypto development are there?

I assume that the secure token should be time-bounded, that both external site and internal auth service should support SSL/TLS (symmetric/asymmetric keys?). 
Am I missing something here? Surely, I am, but what?

Comment: So you want a website that is hosted outside your network, to be available only to those who are inside your network, correct?

Comment: No, the external site is available to external users as well as corporate users. But external users have only limited functionality - they can access only their data. Corporate users can see all the data.

Comment: What you're looking for is something called identity federation.

Answer (score 2):

Make the external site a SAML 2.0 Service Provider (SP).

Set up an internal SAML 2.0 Identity Provider (IdP) to authenticate the corporate users with SAML 2.0 ADFS.  Use SP initiated SSO and have the external site configured to hand off to your IdP with HTTP-POST.

The IdP can be configured to authenticate a user logged into your ActiveDirectory domain with a browser capable of NTLM transparently.  It should just authenticate them and sign an assertion to that effect and redirect them back to the external site.  If they don't have NTLM they'll be promtped for their domain credentials first.

UPDATE: as noted by @Steve the external site still needs to authenticate external users.  Making your external site a SAML SP doesn't solve that.  You could have the external website do some built-in authentication or you could have a different SP endpoint (URL) for external users and use another IdP for them.

Comment: The second part of this is that you have to either configure the site to work with a second IdP for external users, or implement a user auth system within the site itself.

Comment: @alain-odea as far as I understand, to configure ADFS there's a need to have access to a Domain Controller? Or Can I create my own IdP? If latter, then how?

Comment: You do need access to a Domain Controller to configure SAML for ActiveDirectory.  ADFS is the most direct and probably best supported option.  It gives you a SAML 2.0 IdP directly integrated and maintained by Microsoft. There's an example of using ADFS to authenticate to a Tomcat application behind IIS which is using Shibboleth SP to accept the assertions from ADFS as an IdP. It also provides an example of using ADFS as an SP to accept assertions from Shibboleth IdP https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg317734(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @alain-odea, its a pity, I don't have such permissions (access and control over a DC). Is there a way to implement some kind of a custom IdP?

Comment: @prot definitely.  I installed Shibboleth IdP v3 and configured it to use a local LDAP server on my laptop.  There is a docker repo that sets up a LDAP server container for you if you want something more plug and play. You'll still need to configure Shibboleth IdP to talk to it though.  https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap/blob/stable/README.md